# lower_case_table_names in MYSQL 8 in google cloud platform

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have been using `google cloud platform mysql-5.7` and this version of mysql contains a flag named as:

```
lower_case_table_names
```

Now recently I start working in `MYSQL-8` of `gcp` and gcp does not provide `lower_case_table_names` flag in mysql-8 according to this document:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags

**Now I want to know is there any alternative flag that gcp provide in order to perform actions that lower_case_table_names flag use to do**

or is there any other way(beside changes in code level) to perform not case sensitive actions on mysql tables and columns.

Comment: This article will understand why this flag cannot be changed: https://mysql.wisborg.dk/2019/04/14/install-mysql-8-on-linux-with-lower_case_table_names-1/

Comment: There is Future Request for this. You can track it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169608169